# Woocommerce HTML email template add product image

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to add product image to my html email template that is custom build by me.

I can not able to find any hook that will add product image to my html email template with below shared code

I'd appreciate it if you helped.

```
<table style="width: 70%" >
<tr>
<th style="font-weight: normal; width: 24%" >
<p style="margin-left: 30px;">Produkt Artikel :</p>
</th>
<th style="width: 150%; height: 25px;font-weight: normal; text-align: left;" >
<div class="inputt"  class="inputt"  style="background-color: #e9ecef; padding: 7px; margin-left: 15px;border-radius: 0.55rem; height: 30px;" >
<?php  echo $product_name; ?>
</div>
</th>
</tr>
</table>

<table style="width: 70%">
<tr>
<th style="font-weight: normal; width: 22%" >
<p style="margin-left: 30px;">Produktdetail :</p>
</th>
<th style="width: 150%; height: 25px;font-weight: normal; text-align: left;" >
<div class="inputt"  style="background-color: #e9ecef; padding: 7px; margin-left: 15px;border-radius: 0.55rem; width: 50%;">
<?php  wc_display_item_meta($item, array('label_before' =>esc_attr( $text_align), ) ); ?>
</div>
</th>
</tr>
</table>
<table style="width: 70%" >
<tr>
<th style="font-weight: normal; width: 22%" >
<p style="margin-left: 30px;">Vorname : </p>
</th>
<th style="width: 30%; height: 25px;font-weight: normal; text-align: left;" >
<div class="inputt"  class="inputt"  style="background-color: #e9ecef; padding: 7px; margin-left: 15px;border-radius: 0.55rem; height: 30px;" >
<?php echo wp_kses_post( wptexturize( $order->get_billing_first_name() ) ); ?>
</div>
</th>
<th style="font-weight: normal; width: 22%" >
<p style="margin-left: 30px;">Nachname :</p>
</th>
<th style="width: 150%; height: 25px;font-weight: normal; text-align: left;" >
<div class="inputt"  class="inputt"  style="background-color: #e9ecef; padding: 7px; margin-left: 15px;border-radius: 0.55rem; height: 30px;" >
<?php echo wp_kses_post( wptexturize( $order->get_billing_last_name() ) ); ?>
</div>
</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post some code to get more reference and detail for your question?

Comment: what email exactly do you want it?

Comment: New Order mail.